# List index out of range on if statement

Tags: python, list

I looked at other Stack Overflow posts on this question but I still don't understand the error of this program I'm attempting to make. I don't get why the List index is out of range in the if statement inside the for loop. Please could someone explain it to me and what to change to fix it.

```
order = ["12345678", "2", "12345670", "2", "11111111", "3", "87654321", "8"]
orderCount = 0
productCount = 0

file = open("file.txt", "r")

print(len(order))

while orderCount < len(order):
    for line in file:
        product = line.split(",")
        print(orderCount)
        if order[orderCount] == product[0]:
            totalCost = float(order[1]) * float(product[2].strip('\n'))
            receipt = product[productCount], product[1], order[1], product[2].strip('\n'), str(totalCost)
            receipt = " ".join(receipt)
            print(receipt)

        else:
            print("Product not found.")
        orderCount += 2
```

Comment: `orderCount` is larger than the largest index of `order`.  You're trying to stop this with that `while` loop, but ask yourself: When does the loop check how big `orderCount` is versus when does `orderCount` get bigger

Answer (score 5):

You check the orderCount in the while loop, but increase it in the the for loop.

You could remove the while loop and put this inside the for loop:

```
if len(order) <= orderCount:
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking to make sure that `orderCount` is less than `len(order)` on the iterations of your inner loop; a file with 4 or more lines will cause `orderCount` to end up at 8 or above, which is out of bounds for the `order` list.

One easy way to fix this (although you'll have to evaluate yourself whether this will give you the desired behavior, I can't speak to that) is to break out of the inner loop when `orderCount >= len(order)`, like this:

```
while orderCount < len(order):
    for line in file:
        ...
        orderCount += 2
        if orderCount >= len(order):
             break
```